# Saving Yahoo or Google video chat

Tags: gmail, recording, yahoo-messenger, google-hangouts, video-chat

how can I save a video chat done using Yahoo Messenger or Gmail.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to get a screen recording program.  See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/6801/what-is-the-best-software-for-desktop-recording) for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This article from Yahoo! Answers seemed to have worked for someone else...FWIW...

> "Copy & past the link at myfolder." by Y!A user hujan_dingins (user no longer exists)

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070618085345AAHQQRs

---

A page from SuperShareware suggesting some more solutions for Yahoo Chat, however this page looks somewhat shady... **At your own risk:**
http://www.supershareware.com/record-yahoo-video-chat-free-free/

Comment: which link am i supposed to copy and paste. i don't get any link.!! where can we get the link when we do video chat in yahoo messenger or gmail.!

Comment: @pragadheesh: to be honest, i have never used Yahoo Video chat...sorry! :(